# apply my policy(policy.rego) bydfault to my opa

Tags: open-policy-agent

I am using an ci/cd application called concourse which got recently, integrated to OPA . Our concourse setup is running in k8s. I am trying to run the opa as a sidecar it recommended with below configuration./

sidecar configuration : https://github.com/concourse/concourse-chart/blob/master/values.yaml#L1530

```
sidecarContainers:
  - name: opa
    image: openpolicyagent/opa:0.21.0
    args:
      - "run"
      - "--server"
```

I want to apply some policies as well. my policy file is  *concourse_policy.rego*

```
package concourse

default allow = true
allow = false {
    input.action == "UseImage"
    input.data.privileged == true
```

I am not sure, how to make this policy applied bydefault to my opa, when sidecar is running. How can do it. ?

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to either mount a volume containing your policies into the container and start OPA pointing to those, or you could use OPA's [bundle API](https://www.openpolicyagent.org/docs/latest/management/#bundles) to retrieve the policies from a remote endpoint.